# Get a file from a load balanced server in Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing, file-sharing

I've a load balanced server on production environment for my application. The server is on Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm running a web application that creates and save a file into a folder on the web path. So I need to create a job that copy this file into another server. 
The main idea is that a file watcher checks for the file and then copy it instantly. But how can I know in what server it's the file?

Please avoid "why you don't" answers to get a directly answer, if it's someone.

Comment: Saying that you don't want other solutions/strategies to the problem on a sysadmin board is a little off-putting. A good problem-solver will always take a look at the whole process, not just the small bit that you're presenting. This comes from deep experience, in most cases.

Comment: Yeah i know, I comment on the answer that I have a little control on the environment because it's production. It's sad for me too. Even I can't deploy on staging, just on dev. It's a P1 application

Comment: @Leandro if thats really the answer then you really ought to be involving other members of your team to solve and evaluate this problem isntead of trying to force fit a cube through a round hole.  These kinds of problems require the entire team, dev and systems to work together.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to change the IIS configuration? You could have the folder configured as a virtual directory on all of your NLB nodes that points to a central network location. No code changes required, and all nodes see the same set of files, instantly.

Comment: really good point, I need to check with the third partner but i think it's possible. I think i can only change IIS configuration

Comment: This is pretty much the same answer as the "better yet" from Brent above, Leandro.

Comment: @mfinni Depends how you read it. I assumed that "reconfigure your web application" meant, "change your code to use a network path" rather than reconfiguring IIS. Clearly Leandro didn't infer that he might be referring to a Virtual Directory either.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use some of the built-in file and folder replication technologies like DFS to replicate and store files automatically.  Or better yet reconfigure your web application to store whatever files you have directly to a network storage device instead of locally.

Comment: Change production environment implies changes on Staging and Dev environments. Also production is handled by a third company, I'm on CIO Development Software team.

Comment: Well if you don't control the production environment how do you ever expect to be able to get files from it.  Get your CIO to help you out then.

Comment: We implemented jobs for data migration without touching the environments. In any case I thank you for your answer but is not a directly answer to my question.